# How to enter into BusyBox when booting?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, boot, busybox

I have occasionally installed `cloud-init` package in Ubuntu, which blocks me from booting. Neither recovery mode works. Because `cloud-init` installed some upstart job configuration.
So I want to enter into busybox to remove `/etc/init/cloud-init*.conf`, but it seems like no way to do it. I can press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+SysRq</kbd> which brings on a rough hack menu, but there is no busybox option. So is it possible? My CDROM is broken so I can't use Live CD too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try adding the string `init=/bin/sh` to the kernel command line in grub. This should bring you into a shell. Then mount the root filesystem read-write with

```
mount / -o remount,rw
```

and make your changes.